# etc shadow file for passwd - calculate not only date but time

Tags: ubuntu, passwd, etc, shadow

I want to know if there is a way to get the last password change date + time stamp ?

Answer (score 1):

According to `man shadow` only days are recorded. If no other changes occurred, you might `stat /etc/shadow`.